# Call VB 32 bit DLL from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dll, 32bit-64bit

This might be a duplicate question but I was not able to find the exact question or good answer which worked for me. So please help me on this.
I had 2 applications written in VB 6.0 Application Audit and PAM. Now we are changing the Audit application to .NET. Application Audit interact with PAM through a DLL.
Audit application call the PAM application. Now when EZ-Audit 32 Bit version. i.e. installed on Program files (x86) is trying to call/instantiate the PAM it failed with error 429 "Cannot create ActiveX component".

But same setup of both the applications (Audit in .NET and PAM in VB) is working fine on a Window XP machine.

I believe that VB.NET 32 bit application should be able to call the VB 32 Bit DLL and interact. Can you please advice me on this. Can you please provide some other link which says how to do this?

Comment: Check the vb.net project compile settings - if it is set to "AnyCPU" you will need to change it to "x86" to force the assembly to compile in 32-bit mode only.  When set to "AnyCPU" the compiler will create both a 32-bit and 64-bit assembly.  If you run an "AnyCPU" compiled program on a 64-bit OS then the 64-bit version will run, but since a 64-bit application cannot load a 32-bit DLL the program will crash.

Comment: what is the OS of the machine it fails on?  Make sure you are using x86 compile options and not "any CPU"

Comment: It is failing on Window 7. thanks for feedback. we will try this and let you also know.

Comment: 32 bit apps installed to `%windir%\system32` on 32 bit machines are actually placed into `%windir\syswow64\` on 64 bit machines.  Is there a hardcoded path there?  Maybe the environment variable paths need to be updated.

Comment: we cahnaged the compine option to target cpu = x86 but still receving the same error. I validated at DLL is refernced to correct path. DLL was registeretd with C:\Window\SysWow64\regsvr32 and present in registey HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{83C9164F-0EB2-4EC3-8BAC-0C72001ABCF6}\ProgID. Any suggetsion what cna be changed or how it can be corrected. Thank You very much!

Comment: Hi Guys, The issue is not yet resolved and we tried few more combinataions. The application PAM has just one DLL so I register that DLL through SysWow64\regsvr32
Placed the DLL into the VB.Net code and checked the debug mode. But it failed on below code: objPamComm = GetObject(, "PAMComm.Comm")
The PAMCOMM.COMM is present in registry as below: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PAMComm.Comm\Clsid

Comment: We tried below statement also in VB.Net code Set objPamComm = New PAMComm.Comm
But it failed with error "Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {83C9164F-0EB2-4EC3-8BAC-0C72001ABCF6} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800a0153."

Comment: I tried running the Dependency Walker on PAMCOMM.DLL in a Window 7 64 Bit machine. And received the error for 
2 Yellow for GPSCV.DLL and IESHMS.DLL (Can’t find the file specified)
1 Red for IEFRAME.DLL 

When I tried running Dependency Walker in  32 bit XP machine (Application is working fine there). I received 2 yellow (WER.DLL and IESHMS.DLL) and one red warning (MPR.DLL)

Comment: I guess IEFRAME can be a reason but this is not directly referenced from the PAMCOMM DLL. Only MSINET.OCX, SigPlus.ocx, MSVBVM60.DLL, dao360.dll, msado15.dll are referenced from PAMCOMM.

Can you please advice what can be next step. What can be checked or change. We don’t want to change anything in PAMCOMM (VB & 32 bit) but Audit (.Net/32 Bit) is open to try anything.